# Quality loss going from Scene window to game window

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out why my model looks good in the scene but the camera renders it cartoonish and flat.

[image: pic]

Comment: Most likely candidates are lighting, or the settings on your camera.  You won't get much of an answer without providing some more detail - but moreover, you might find more luck on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It turned out to be lighting. I set the ambient lighting to white. I light my scene but not my game. I threw in a light and it looks great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be lighting. I had set the ambient lighting to white. It was lighting my scene but not my game. I threw in a new light and it looks great.